# Create a line chart with areas colored differently for each group

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data below

```
cc <- structure(list(
  Cycle = "Average",
  `Die 1` = 100, `Pro 1` = 101, `Est 1` = 97, `Met 1` = 99,
  `Die 2` = 100, `Pro 2` = 101.788432267884, `Est 2` = 97.2, `Met 2` = 99.6194824961948,
  `Die 3` = 100, `Pro 3` = 102, `Est 3` = 97.5, `Met 3` = 99
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

and my goal is to create a line chart with standard errorbars for each point. In the y-axis there will be the numerical values the exist in the 2nd row from column 2 to column 13 and in the x-axis all the values of the 1st row from column 2 to column 13.

There must be only one line not 3 but the area inside the plot must be colored with 3 different colors. The area of the first 4 different, the area of the second 4 different color etc The plot will be like:

[image]

My try:

```
library(ggplot2)


# Extracting the relevant data for plotting
weights <- as.numeric(unlist(cc[1, -1]))
phases <- names(cc)[-1]

# Creating a new data frame for plotting
data_plot <- data.frame(Phase = rep(phases, each = 1), Weight = weights)

# Determine grouping for coloring
data_plot$Group <- rep(1:3, each = 4)

# Creating the plot with different colored areas under the line
ggplot(data_plot, aes(x = Phase, y = Weight, group = 1)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(
    aes(ymin = 0, ymax = Weight, fill = factor(Group)),
    alpha = 0.5,
    color = NA
  ) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Group") +
  labs(
    title = "Weights across EC-3 cycles",
    x = "Phase",
    y = "% weight relative to die"
  )
Error in `geom_ribbon()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `draw_group()`:
! Aesthetics can not vary along a ribbon
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only your `cc` data frame, you can use `annotate` to place the rectangles in the background:

```r
library(tidyverse)

cc %>%
  pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  mutate(name = factor(name, name)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_blank() +
  annotate('rect', xmin = c(0.5, 4.5, 8.5), xmax = c(4.5, 8.5, 12.5),
           ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, color = 'white',
           fill = c('#fce8e8', '#f3dbea', '#ecc4de'), linewidth = 1) +
  geom_line(aes(group = 1), linewidth = 1.5) +
  geom_point(size = 5, shape = 15) +
  scale_y_continuous('% Weight relative to die', limits = c(92, 104)) +
  labs(title = 'Weight across EC - 3 cycles', x = 'Phase') +
  coord_cartesian(expand = FALSE) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 16) +
  theme(plot.title.position = 'plot',
        plot.title = element_text(face = 'bold', hjust = 0.5))
```

[image]

The only thing missing from this compared to the original plot is the error bars, but you have not supplied any data to include these.

In the original image, the rectangles are drawn *over* the lines with a low alpha (high transparency) instead of under them. You could also do this if you prefer by adding the annotate layer after the points and lines, including `alpha = 0.1` in the call to `annotate`, and choosing darker versions of the fill colors.